# installed mdb for angular 6 but it's not working

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4, material-design

I created a new Angular project with .scss styles using the cli.
I installed Angular materials Design.

I am attempting to install material design Bootstraping (MDbootstrap), using this guide

https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/5min-quickstart/

with npm.

I've done everything in the manual several times.

I've checked the app.modules and angular.json files are like the manual specifies.

I have tried several code examples from the official MDB website
https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/forms/forms/

It seems that even though the project compiles, and there are no errors, the material design does not change.

How can I get my project to acknowledge design from MDB?

Code:

app.modules

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
import { CardsCollectionComponent } from './cards-collection/cards-collection.component';
import { EditDialogComponent } from './edit-dialog/edit-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CardComponent,
    CardsCollectionComponent,
    EditDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,  
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),

  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  entryComponents: [EditDialogComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

angular.json

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ],
```

and

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/bookCollection",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [ "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"]
```

Comment: Show an example component that is not displayed as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been almost 3 years since I asked this question, and the answer is so trivial, but maybe it will help someone.

To solve this issue I only needed to restart the server `ng serve` or `npm run start`.

Answer (score 0):

your styles are good. My scripts look like and I added bootstrap npm i bootstrap --save

```
 "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
                            "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ] 

                                                                                                                                              ]
```